# Sending data to controller and update views (Single page architecture)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a little self project and I cannot seem to figure out my problem. If anyone can give some feedback that would be great. Thanks in advance.

So I have php file `index.php`, and in that file I have a div with id `main-container`. Currently in the `main-container` is two divs. The first div contains the starting view you see when the page loads and the second div is the second view for when we update it with jquery ajax.

The first div with id `startview` contains a button element with id `loginbutton`.

Once we click this button element we are supposed to send a request to the controller to hide the div with id `startview` and show the div with id `secondview`.

Here is my index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<script>            
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#loginbutton").click(function(){         

            $.post("controller.php",
            {
                page: "StartView",
                command: "Login"                

            },
            function(data){                 
                $("#main-container").html(data);                        
            });         
        });
    });


</script>

</head>
<body >


 <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 75%; background-color: #325d81" id="main-container">
    <h1>Main-Container</h1>

    <!-- initital view-->
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: yellow;" id='startview'>  
        <h1>Starting View/Page</h1>
        <button type='button' id='loginbutton'>Click to login.</button> 
    </div>

    <!--View after loggin in. -->
    <div class="container-fluid" style="display: none; background-color: orange; width: 75%;" id="secondview">
        <br>
        <h2>Second View/Page</h2>       
    </div>

    <?php //require('views/startview.php');?>

     <!--View after clicking login button. -->
    <?php// require('views/secondview.php');?>  <!--Not Working!??!?!?!? -->
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my controller.php file

```
<?php

$page = $_POST['page'];
$command = $_POST['command'];

// When commands come from StartView
if ($page == 'StartView') { 

    switch($command) {                  

        case 'Login':           

                //Alert the user we recieved the login request
                echo "<script>alert('Received your login request.');</script>";
                // Display MainPage
                echo "<script>$('#startview').hide(); $('#secondview').show();</script>";


            exit();         

        default:            
            exit();
    }
} 
?>
```

Basically my problem is that when the user clicks the loginbutton the secondview does not show. and StartView should be hidden.

Comment: what is the problem or question, you just  explained what you doing

Comment: in ajax success function , use inner divs id to show and hide, not main div. 
$(''#startview).hide(); $('secondview').show();

Comment: @AhmedSunny the secondview div doesnt show after clicking the login button

Comment: can you update the code above with the new changes,

Comment: and please avoid writing js in controller, you can write all js in js for any cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>            
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginbutton").click(function(){         

        $.post("controller.php",
        {
            page: "StartView",
            command: "Login"                

        },
        function(data){                 
            if(data == 1) {
                  alert('Received your login request.');
                  $('#startview').hide(); 
                  $('#secondview').show();
             }                     
        });         
    });
});
</script>
```

Modify your controller file:

```
if ($page == 'StartView') { 

  switch($command) {                  

    case 'Login':           

            echo "1";        

    default:            
        return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did what you did and it didnt worked. Then I changed the returns back into echos and it worked. But can I ask you why I cannot just echo this statement "echo "<script>$('#startview').hide(); $('#secondview').show();</script>";" back from the controller?

Comment: I am trying to avoid echoing/returning numbers from the controller

Comment: My bad. The if statement is not actually a function, so return will not work here. 

You need to read more about Callback function: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

When you want to manipulate something on Front end, you should do it from FrontEnd, not Backend.

Comment: I dont really know what front end vs back end is. I should look it up. My university has taught me nothing after 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna do something like this:

```php
switch ($command) {
  case 'Login':

    return json_encode([
      'message' => 'You\'re succesfully logged in.',
    ]);


    break;
}
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#loginbutton").click(function(){         

          $.post("controller.php",
          {
              page: "StartView",
              command: "Login"                

          },
          function(data){
              data = JSON.parse(data);      
              alert(data.message);
              $('#startview').attr('display', 'none'),
              $('#secondview').attr('display', 'block');
          });
      });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: there is no need for me to return the json_encode. I could easily just echo "You logged in" and the return function could alert(data); thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. I feel like you helped me. Instead of echoing the "$('#startview').attr('display', 'none'),
              $('#secondview').attr('display', 'block');" from the controller ill place it in the return function